# Return default record if no other related record exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Say I have a table defined such that:

```
Entities has_many Images  
Images has_one Entity
```

I have a record in the Images table that has no value for entity_id that I would like to be the default image for any new entity.

When I use:

```
@entities.images.find(:all, :conditions => ['image_type = ?', 'avatar])
```

I would like the default record from the Images table to be returned iff there is no image for the current entity

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method for this in your `Entity` model (best practice is to use singular names for models.)

```
class Entity

  def avatar_images
    avatars = images.find(:all, :conditions => ['image_type = ?', 'avatar'])
    if avatars.empty?
      avatars = Image.find(:all, :conditions =>
        ['entity_id is null and image_type = ?', 'avatar'])
    end
    avatars
  end

end
```

Then just call that method in your controller to get either the avatar images belonging to the entity, or the default images if it has none.

```
@avatars = @entity.avatar_images
```

**Edit:**

It is probably a good idea to generalize this method to accept an image type as parameter, to make it more versatile:

```
class Entity

  def images_of_type(type)
    list = images.find(:all, :conditions => ['image_type = ?', type])
    if list.empty?
      list = Image.find(:all, :conditions =>
        ['entity_id is null and image_type = ?', type])
    end
    list
  end

end
```

Then in your controller:

```
@avatars = @entity.images_of_type('avatar')
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Very simple and does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must, you can do something like the next piece of code, although I would not really recommend it:

```
  class << self
    def find (*arguments)
      begin
        result_set = super(*arguments)
      rescue
        result_set = []
      ensure
        result_set =
          Image.find(:first, 
                     :conditions =>['entity_id is null and image_type = ?', 'avatar']
                    ) if result_set.blank?
      end
      result_set
    end
  end
```

The way why I do not recommend this is because it modifies the normal way find() works, I would recommend simply making a new method that encapsulates what you want to do, like:

```
def find_or_default (*arguments)
  begin
      begin
        result_set = Image.find(*arguments)
      rescue
        result_set = []
      ensure
        result_set =
          Image.find(:first, 
                     :conditions =>['entity_id is null and image_type = ?', 'avatar']
                    ) if result_set.blank?
      end
      result_set
  end
end
```

Comment: I modified the code a bit because I had a variable that was really not needed. (The result of sketching code ;))